# Excel data validation - how to limit input to digits and dashes?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to make data validation for phone numbers in EXCEL. Pattern should contain only digits and dashed. And at least one dash should be present. How can I acheve this without VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Data Validation.

### How To

- Go to *Data Validation* and set the *Allow* drop-down to "Custom".
- Use the following in the Formula field (assuming the first cell in your range is `A1`):

  =ISNUMBER( SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-","") * 1)

---

### Explanation

The `SUBSTITUTE` function looks at the value in cell `A1` with every dash replaced with nothing (i.e. removed).

The characters left are multiplied by 1.  If the characters contain only digits (0-9) then this action returns a number.  If there are letters or symbols other than dashes this returns an error.

Finally, the `ISNUMBER` function returns `TRUE` if the result above is a number.  It returns `FALSE` if the result is anything other than a number including an error.

---

### Allow Additional Characters

To allow additional characters, include a series of nested `SUBSTITUTE` functions, one for each character.

**Allow Digits (numbers), Dashes & Spaces**

ex. 123-456-7890 or 123 456 7890

```
=ISNUMBER(  SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""), " ", "")  * 1)
```

**Allow Digits (numbers), Dashes, Spaces, Parenthesis**

ex. (123) 456-7890

```
=ISNUMBER(  SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE(A1,"-",""), " ", ""), "(", ""), ")", "")  * 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Would a Custom Number Format suffice? `###-###-####`

Limit the input to whole numbers.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

What you are asking is a bit more complex than what you need, and likely more complex than what you think.

Instead of requiring users to enter phone numbers in such a specific format (What if they add parenthesis before their area code? What about a space between digit blocks? What about someone who enters 6 numbers with a dash? What about 20 numbers and 20 dashes?), consider just applying specific formatting rules against an entry of solely numbers. If you do that, your data validation would simply be "Must enter whole numbers" and the formatting will automatically show how it looks.

There's already a special "Phone Numbers" format, so you don't even need to apply any special rules to make that work.